# SVN - GIT mirror

Tags: git, svn, mirror

I have a SVN central repository with many branches and tags. But now I want to start using GIT for the development team ( As in I need to set up a GIT server). So I was given a task to mirror the SVN repo into GIT so that any commit that goes into GIT server's master should also commit to SVN. I was going to use the approach given in 
https://github.com/soxofaan/git-svn-mirroring
If i use git svn clone, it will give me a git repository which is not a bare. So other members of the team cannot add it as a remote. How should I go about it?

Should I make another bare repo, adding this mirror(git svn clone) as its remote and then pulling changes from it and then dcommiting it to SVN?

Answer (score 2):

When setting up Git mirror for SVN repository, there's a problem of conflicting simultaneous commit and push to Git and SVN at the same time.

You can have a look at [SVN Mirror add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.tmatesoft.subgit.stash-svn-importer/server/overview) for [Bitbucket Server](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/download) (preferable option) or [SubGit](http://www.subgit.com/), which do exactly what you describe but not based on git-svn script.

If you choose the first option, you can follow this [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M4QgRKsZzIc&t=52).
If you choose the second option, follow this [HOWTO](http://www.subgit.com/howto.html).

I'm one of SubGit developers.